# Get list of Virtual machine sizes in a region using Azure Service Management (Classic) API

Tags: c#, azure

How can i get the list of available virtual machine sizes in a particular azure location. I have seen that there is an endpoint available  in resource manager API for the same at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt269440.aspx
Is same information is available through Azure Service Management (Classic) API?

Answer (score 1):

try with below code this will work for me

```
AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(your - authserviceurl + your - tenantdomain);
UserCredential uc = new UserCredential(Api - username, Api - password);
token = authenticationContext.AcquireToken("https://management.core.windows.net/", API - nativetenantid, uc);

var credentials = new TokenCredentials(token);
var computeClient = new ComputeManagementClient(credentials) { SubscriptionId = Your - SubscriptionId };
var virtualMachineSize = computeClient.VirtualMachineSizes.List(locationName).ToList();
```

i am using **Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.dll**, v10.0.0.0 version for this .
upper example i am using token base authentication. you can also try with certificate base authentication.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.dll, v15.0.0.0 and the ComputeManagementClient class doesn't have the VirtualMachineSizes.  Was this functionality moved to another class?

Answer (score 0):

The following [reference document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn499770.aspx) suggests that it should be possible.

> **URI Parameter**
>
> *location* - Optional. Returns VM Images from the specified location.The location parameter is only available using version 2014-05-01 or higher.

Comment: the referred document doesn't contain any information about vm sizes.

Comment: From the same page, the response body contains

LogicalSizeInGB - Specifies the size, in GB, of the operating system disk.

Comment: I think you got it wrong. What i am asking about is actually virtual machine instance sizes (e.g. standard_A0) that are available with respect to locations in an azure subscription.